# Golang's type system behaviour - dividing an int by an implicit float

Tags: go

I was experimenting lately with golang's type system and encountered an interesting (or not) behaviour related to floats:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    doesntWork()
    works()
}

func doesntWork() {
    x := 1234
    y := x / 100000.0
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.8f", y)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
}

func works() {
    x := 1234
    y := float64(x) / 100000.0
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.8f", y)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6axmtCslmU)

I think that in the case presented in the example above, in procedure `doesntWork()`, golang does not automatically "assume" `float32/64` when dividing an `int` by an implicit `float`? Is that correct? Could anyone point me towards some docs or specs where I could learn more about how golang behaves in situations like the one above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here `10000.0` is not float64/32 it is a numeric constant. Go will assume the type of `x` in this case for the expression and `truncate` the constant 100000.0 to integer

```
func doesntWork() {
    x := 1234
    y := x / 100000.0
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.8f", y)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
}
```

If you update it to

```
func doesntWork() {
    x := 1234
    y := x / float64(100000.0)
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.8f", y)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
}
```

it will error out saying

```
 invalid operation: x / float64(100000) (mismatched types int and float64)
```

Similarly if you change the constant to 100000.111 where `truncating` to integer will no longer give the same value it will error out

```
func doesntWork() {
    x := 1234
    y := x / 100000.1
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.8f", y)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
}
```

It will error out saying

```
constant 100000 truncated to integer
```

Comment: @kostix forgot to share the link, nice

Comment: @kostix thanks that is exactly the link I was looking for;